# Form Data Upload with IFormFile is Null

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I have a .Net Core 2.2 web api that receives form uploads with an IFormFile property on an object.

```cs
public class UploadFile
{
  [FromForm(Name = "id")]
  public int id { get; set; }
  [FromForm(Name = "imageFile")]
  public IFormFile imageFile { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadMedia([FromForm] UploadFile uploadFile)
{
  ...
}
```

And I have a client using .Net 4.5+ that calls the web api to upload:

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
  {
    content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
    content.Add(new StringContent(id.ToString()), "id");
    using (var filestream = new FileStream(info.file_location, FileMode.Open))
    {
      content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "imageFile");
      using (var message = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/uploads", content))
      {
        var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the call into the web api, but the imageFile property is always null. The id property is correct. If I use Postman to test the web api, the imageFile property is passed correctly so the issue seems to be in the client implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the StreamContent and FileStream. To get this to work I changed it to:

```cs
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
content.Add(byteArrayContent, "imageFile", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```